# Dedicated drawing surface in Java like Android's SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, drawing

I am looking for a dedicated drawing surface in Java to draw 2D very fast in succession, very much like Android's [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). I have been using JPanels but I am not sure about the performance and efficiency when calling `repaint()` multiple times. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) says that:

> If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible.

Note the *as soon as possible*. I want instantaneous. Using the SurfaceView in Android I had full control of the Canvas and could draw when I wanted.

Should I be using for instance the [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) from AWT or [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) from Swing, or something else? Note that  I want a dedicated drawing area and I do not care about other compontents. I would like to register mouse events though. And again, I want the full control to draw on the area without having to call repaint or some other method, like I do with SurfaceView on another Thread.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074780/dedicated-drawing-surface-in-java/) but now I feel like I can be more specific thanks to the answers from that question.